# How to get date time using time zone offset in js

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a time zone offset like `-7` now I want the date-time of that particular offset?
How Can I get this in js? Thanks.

Comment: `let d = new Date(); d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() - 7); d.toISOString().replace('Z','-07:00');`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's `dateObj.getTimezoneOffset()` method returns the time-zone offset in minutes for the current locale. The time-zone offset is the minutes in difference, the Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) is relative to your local time.

For example, if your time zone is GMT+10, -600 will be returned. Daylight savings time prevents this value from being a constant.

Comment: Rather than "current locale", it would be more appropriate to use "current system settings", since that is what is actually used and may not be consistent with the location.